# Using API Controller in Page Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm starting learning asp.net core, and I have problems with understanding some basic patterns. Can I use ApiController inside PageController?

For example

```
//Home controller
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var artists = await _artistController.GetAll();

    var t = artists.GetValue();

    var indexModel = new Models.Pages.IndexModel
    {
        Artists = artists.GetValue() //Extension method
    };
    return View(indexModel);
}
```

```
//ArtistRestController
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Artist>>> GetAll()
{
    try
    {
        return Ok(await _repository.GetAll());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

It works, but is is ok by design? Maybe I should directly call `_repository.GetAll()` and do not use other controller?

Comment: Yes.You may inject your Repository to HomeController and use it to get the data you want.

Comment: Are any client side code accessing the ArtistRestController/Getall  ?

Comment: if you dont want to expose the GetAll method to the outside world, you can create a private function inside the controller and remove the HttpGet attribute

Comment: Assume, that I want to have some funcionallity in Api (for example getting all artists, or posting new one) and use the same things in HomeController (have list of all artists on page, or 'Add new' button). Which approach is better - using ApiController in PageController or just inject repository and duplicate code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should avoid using one Controller in another Controller. For Controller, it is used to handle http request from client. It is unreasonable to use it as a class even through it is a class.

Second, for combining `ApiController` and `PageController` will make your application unstatable and too coupling. If you change anything later in `ArtistRestController.GetAll` will make `HomeController` broken. And, for your current code, if there are some exception in `PageController`, your `ApiController` will be down.

You should inject `repository` to query the data.